# Database handling from web service - how to improve the performance?

Tags: c#, .net, database, rest

I created a web service which is called from the client side to store the data into the database. These data are sent every 200 ms from a single user and each time the data are sent the database connection is opened and closed which I believe is not good for performance.

The data are stored by calling REST.StoreAcceleration() method and SQLWorks.StoreAcceleration() the following way:

```
public Response StoreAcceleration(string strSessionString, string strMeasurementTime, string strAccelerationX, string strAccelerationY, string strAccelerationZ)
    {
        SQLWorks sqlWorks = new SQLWorks();
        Response response = new Response();
        try
        {
            string strTime = strMeasurementTime.Replace("_", " ");
            DateTime measurementTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", null);
            double accelerationX = Convert.ToDouble(strAccelerationX.Replace(".", ","));
            double accelerationY = Convert.ToDouble(strAccelerationY.Replace(".", ","));
            double accelerationZ = Convert.ToDouble(strAccelerationZ.Replace(".", ","));

            sqlWorks.StoreAcceleration(strSessionString, measurementTime, accelerationX, accelerationY, accelerationZ);

            response.Successful = true;
            response.Comment = "Stored!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string sDummy = ex.ToString();
            response.Comment = "an error occured!";
            response.Successful = false;
        }

        return response;
    }

public bool StoreAcceleration(string strStringSession, DateTime receivedTime, double accelerationX, double accelerationY, double accelerationZ)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string select =
            "INSERT INTO acceleration (session_id, measurement_time, acceleration_x, acceleration_y, acceleration_z) VALUES (@sessionID, @measurementTime, @accelerationX, @accelerationY, @accelerationZ)";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, conn);
        int sessionID = getSessionID(strStringSession);
        if(sessionID == 0)
            return false;
        updateSessions(sessionID);
        string strRecordTime = receivedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sessionID", sessionID.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("measurementTime", strRecordTime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accelerationX", accelerationX.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accelerationY", accelerationY.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accelerationZ", accelerationZ.ToString());
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string sDummy = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The problem here is that SqlConnection is opened and closed on every method call.

I would appreciate if anyone could suggest how to improve the solution in order to prevent frequent database connection opening/closing.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem, or are you just optimizing for the heck of it?

Comment: If there is a performance problem, I'd take a closer look at the database side of things. Even though I cleaned up the code a bit, it's not gonna be noticeably faster. *Unless* connection pooling was actually disabled of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a connection pool set up, your database connection will *not* get closed. Never mind the `conn.Close()`. From MSDN:

> The Close method rolls back any
>   pending transactions. It then releases
>   the connection to the connection pool,
>   or closes the connection if connection
>   pooling is disabled.

See here to set it up, if you're not already using it:
[SQL Server connection pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) and [connection strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx).

Basically, unless you have `pooling=false` or something similar in your connection string, it should already be active. However, you might want to set some `MinPoolSize` to always have a couple of connections ready to be used.

---

By the way, are you storing the received time as actual strings? Otherwise you can get rid of the whole `ToString(..)` thing. ADO.NET will make sure the date doesn't get misinterpreted. The same goes for the other values really; why are you converting them to strings?

Lastly, `SqlCommand` implements IDisposable, so you should be disposing it, much like the connection. I'd suggest rewriting to something like this:

```
public bool StoreAcceleration(string strStringSession, DateTime receivedTime, double accelerationX, double accelerationY, double accelerationZ)
{
    string select =
        "INSERT INTO acceleration (session_id, measurement_time, acceleration_x, acceleration_y, acceleration_z) VALUES (@sessionID, @measurementTime, @accelerationX, @accelerationY, @accelerationZ)";

    int sessionID = getSessionID(strStringSession);
    if (sessionID == 0)
        return false;
    updateSessions(sessionID);

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sessionID", sessionID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("measurementTime", receivedTime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accelerationX", accelerationX);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accelerationY", accelerationY);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accelerationZ", accelerationZ);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You no longer need the `Close()` call in a `finally` block. The `using` block will implicitly call `Dispose()` when the variable `conn` falls out of scope. That will in turn call the `Close()` method internally.

Comment: +1 excellent advice - especially on using the `using` statements. Way too few ADO.NET programmers seems to know and embrace that...

Answer (score 0):

By default the connection pooling is enabled, so re-open a database connection is not that expensive like we thought. It is perfectly fine to open and close connection for each web service request.